# What datetime format is this and how do I parse it?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format, ccxt

I have some data that I'm pulling from an API and the date is formatted like this: '1522454400000'

Not sure how to parse it but this is what I have (unsuccessfully tried)

```
df = DataFrame(test)
df.columns = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
df.set_index('Date')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit = 'd')
```

where the variable `test` is a list of the underlying data. this incorrectly parses the data as year being 1970.

The result of the parse:

```
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000
```

Any ideas?

**********************   EDIT   ************************************

Python version: 3

Pandas version. 0.23.0

Here is a working example for reproducibility. But first, here are the facts I have discovered.

DATE FORMAT: 64-bit Unix Timestamp in milliseconds since Epoch 1 Jan 1970

TIMEZONE: UTC

MY TIMEZONE: UTC + 4 (the desired datetime index)

The code:

```
import bitmex
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import datetime
import ccxt

api_connector = ccxt.bitmex({
    'enableRateLimit': True
})

#get OHLCV Data
testdata = api_connector.fetch_ohlcv('XBTZ18', '1h')

df2 = DataFrame(testdata)
df2.columns = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
#df2.set_index('Date')
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.Date, unit='ms')
df3 = df2.drop(['Date'],
              axis =1)
df3.tail()
```

This returns:

```
Open    High    Low Close   Volume
Date                    
2018-07-06 00:00:00 6538.5  6555.0  6532.5  6537.0  176836
2018-07-06 01:00:00 6537.0  6535.5  6520.5  6524.5  139735
2018-07-06 02:00:00 6524.5  6542.5  6525.5  6542.5  59759
2018-07-06 03:00:00 6542.5  6545.0  6538.0  6538.0  121410
2018-07-06 04:00:00 6538.0  6538.5  6477.5  6525.0  764125
```

Close! but no cigar. Today's date is 8/31/2018 so I would at least expect it to be in the correct month.

What am I doing wrong, folks?

Comment: imo the 1970 thing is related to the epoch on UNIX system (january 1, 1970). My guess is, having an error in the parsing give you only the epoch, not the time between. src: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WorkingWithTime

Comment: If you know the year 1970 is incorrect, then presumably you know what _is_ correct, or at least a ballpark—so you should put that information in the question. Because you happened to picked a time in the recent past, in a format very close to a familiar one that some of us have to stare at every day, and were looking for a UTC midnight timestamp, you got lucky and a few of us recognized it quickly, but in general, you shouldn't rely on luck like that or you usually won't get answers.

Comment: Thanks all. I have a sense of the timeframe and do know 1970 to be out of it. I also know that this is a daily time series (because the function pulling the data has a parameter for it). But I'm unable to parse the dates and set it as my index with the responses here. Will keep trying

Comment: I have no idea what your data source is, but are you sure that (a) it has the right date set, and (b) it’s giving you current data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is almost certainly a variation on ["Unix time"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time): instead of seconds since the 1 Jan 1970 epoch, it's *milliseconds* since the 1 Jan 1970 epoch:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int('1522454400000') / 1000)
datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 31, 0, 0)
```

That certainly looks like a reasonable date. And it even looks like it probably is UTC, not local time (unless you happen to be in England, or weren't expecting it to be exactly at midnight).

---

I don't think any of Pandas' built-in formats (which are actually just wrappers around formats from `datetime` and/or `dateutil`) exactly matches this, so you'll probably need to either do what I did about (convert to int and treat it as a number) or do the stringy equivalent (chop off the last 3 characters and then treat as a string of a UNIX timestamp).

The first one seems simpler:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(int('1522454400000'), unit='ms')
Timestamp('2018-03-31 00:00:00')
```

In fact, it'll even work directly on strings, doing the conversion implicitly:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime('1522454400000', unit='ms')
Timestamp('2018-03-31 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Good to know that it can work directly on strings. +1

Comment: @ALollz Yeah, I actually didn't know that until I tried it by accident. Pandas always surprises me, and not always in a bad way. :)

Comment: When I run this I still get the same 1970 result, not what you get above. Any ideas why?   df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index, unit='ms')                  My ultimate goal is to have these dates parsed and act as the index of my pandas dataframe. Having some trouble there. Thanks again all. And @abarnert you rock for find that string trick!

Comment: @user2179795 Can you [edit] your question to give us a complete example, with sample data? Also, do you get 1970 even when running exactly the code in this answer, or only with your sample data? If so, what versions of Python and Pandas (and, while we're at it, dateutil) do you have?

Comment: @abarnert et al. would love to get your thoughts on the example above!